# Using screen.width to detect tablets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect if the client is using a tablet in JavaScript. I do not want to use CSS3 or UserAgents if I can. One method that came into my mind was using `screen.width` property inside the browser to get the device width and detect tablets if the `screen.width` is less than a certain threshold.

Do you guys think this would be a good solution?

What is the support for this property? Do most tablets support this feature?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What would happen to such a solution if the tablet is flipped?

Comment: hmm good point, would it change? I should test that

Comment: the screen.width doesn't seem to change when the tablet is flipped

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think you are going to achieve what you want with this approach. If you really wanna do this with only javascript and no "magic way" (CSS3, UserAgents, etc ...), I suggest you to simple add a "switch button" just like language buttons ... something like "Switch to view : tablet / desktop".

Comment: good suggestion but unfortunately this is not an option for what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Well, I hope you find a way :)
But if you find yourself out of ... hmm ... ideas, this might be  really helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery